# Azure functions V2 possible to buffer log calls?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, log4net

I want to reduce the amount of logging in an Azure Function V2 and I am only interested when an exception occurs. When an exception occurs, I want the entire log history (including any previous info, warn, etc.) to be sent to the log appender. So setting the log level to error in the configuration is not sufficient for my use case.

Is it possible to set up the ILogger to buffer logs and finally a flush call to commit the logging?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReactiveX Buffer operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) to emit a collection of buffered items.